# Find definition of ex command

Tags: ex-mode

Normally when I try to trace back a setting to where it was set in my vim config (or plugins) I use something like:

```
:verbose set undodir
  undodir=~/.vimundo
        Last set from ~/.vimrc line 62
```

To discover this. How do I find this location for the definition of an ex command? For example I have `:A` defined somehow, but I'm not sure where it's coming from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `verbose command` for this like so:

```
:verbose command A
    Name              Args Address Complete    Definition
!b| A                 *    .       customlist  :execute s:edit_command("<mods>", "edit<bang>", <count>, <f-args>)
        Last set from ~/dev/dotfiles/vim/bundle/vim-projectionist/autoload/projectionist.vim line 597
!b| AD                *    .       customlist  :execute s:edit_command("<mods>", "read<bang>", <count>, <f-args>)
        Last set from ~/dev/dotfiles/vim/bundle/vim-projectionist/autoload/projectionist.vim line 597
!b| AE                *    .       customlist  :execute s:edit_command("<mods>", "edit<bang>", <count>, <f-args>)
        Last set from ~/dev/dotfiles/vim/bundle/vim-projectionist/autoload/projectionist.vim line 597
!b| AO                *    .       customlist  :execute s:edit_command("<mods>", "drop<bang>", <count>, <f-args>)
        Last set from ~/dev/dotfiles/vim/bundle/vim-projectionist/autoload/projectionist.vim line 597
!b| AS                *    .       customlist  :execute s:edit_command("<mods>", "split<bang>", <count>, <f-args>)
        Last set from ~/dev/dotfiles/vim/bundle/vim-projectionist/autoload/projectionist.vim line 597
!b| AT                *    .       customlist  :execute s:edit_command("<mods>", "tabedit<bang>", <count>, <f-args>)
        Last set from ~/dev/dotfiles/vim/bundle/vim-projectionist/autoload/projectionist.vim line 597
!b| AV                *    .       customlist  :execute s:edit_command("<mods>", "vsplit<bang>", <count>, <f-args>)
        Last set from ~/dev/dotfiles/vim/bundle/vim-projectionist/autoload/projectionist.vim line 597
!|  Abolish           +    0       custom      :exec s:dispatcher(<bang>0,<line1>,<line2>,<count>,[<f-args>])
        Last set from ~/dev/dotfiles/vim/bundle/vim-abolish/plugin/abolish.vim line 630
|   Autoformat        ?    %       filetype    let winview=winsaveview()|wviminfo|<line1>,<line2>call s:TryAllFormatters(<f-args>)|call winrestview(winview)|rviminfo
        Last set from ~/dev/dotfiles/vim/bundle/vim-autoformat/plugin/autoformat.vim line 351
|   AutoformatLine    ?    .       filetype    let winview=winsaveview()|wviminfo|<line1>,<line2>call s:TryAllFormatters(<f-args>)|call winrestview(winview)|rviminfo
        Last set from ~/dev/dotfiles/vim/bundle/vim-autoformat/plugin/autoformat.vim line 357
```